# How can the invitee, programmatically, decline a Game Center invitation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

When sending an invitation with your own custom interface, you install an invitee response handler:

```
request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse response) {
    NSLog(@"INVITEE ANSWERED: %d", response);
};
```

From the invitee point of view, they receive a `GKInvite` object. If they start match using this object, then the inviter will receive a `GKInviteeResponseAccepted` value in their response handler.

One type of response is `GKInviteeResponseDeclined`, implying that there is a way to decline a `GKInvite` object. **How can the invitee, programmatically, decline an invitation?**

iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `GKTurnBasedMatch`, you can call `declineInvite` right on the match itself!

God knows why they didn't make it that easy with `GKMatch`. I don't know how to do this for a regular `GKMatch`, which is maddening.

Best of luck!